# Trying to include header for vsnprintf throws error in compiling

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, linux-kernel-headers

What is the header file for `vsnprintf` in the kernel? Can anyone please tell me this, I have kernel 5.14 and I am not sure what headers are default on my system. I have a number of different kernel headers installed, these are:

```
linux-headers-5.11.0-25
linux-headers-5.11.0-40
linux-headers-5.11.0-25-generic
linux-headers-5.11.0-40-generic
linux-headers-5.11.0-38
linux-headers-5.11.0-38-generic
```

Which one should be the default? But i like to ask what is the header file for function `vsnprintf`?

Comment: I tried to include <lib/vsprintf.h> no luck

Comment: kernel modules need to be compiled with the headers and config file matching the kernel in which they are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the source code for Linux v5.11, the correct header seems to be [`linux/kernel.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.11/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L333). It's the same file for Linux v5.14.

To check which headers you should use for your currently running kernel use the command `uname -r` which should tell you the correct version. You can then compile using those and an appropriate `Makefile`: see [the documentation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.11/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L333) for more info.